# Codemirror Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, codemirror

I am using the autocomplete addon for Javascript.

I want to know if it is possible that the variables from the code are in the hint list. Now only javascript methods are in the hints.

So, when I have for example this code:

```
function myTestFunction () {
}
var myTestVar;
```

So when the user types myTest and hits CTRL + Space there should be the hints myTestFunction and myTestVar

Is this somehow possible?